# how to export datatable cell with image into a pdf file using pdfmake

Tags: javascript, html, datatable, pdfmake

I followed this link https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/pdfImage.html and able to get datatable working with pdfmake. However if a column (or a cell) contains image, that cell is not getting exported into pdf. How can i tweek this library to include image in the exported file.  it appears buttons.html5.min.js has the logic to export the data. however, i could not figure out how can individually handle cell data. Thanks for your help in advance.

### e.g My table looks like the following

|col1 (string) | col2 (png image) | col3(string)|
|col1 (string) | empty | col3(string)|
|col1 (string) | col2 (png image) | col3(string)|

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble with this pdfmaker you can try the **jsPDF** as well. The **jsPDF** allows you to put images and strings and organize them by coords.

The problem is that I couldn't export the table itself to the pdf, instead I drew a "table" using lines that the **jsPDF** disponibilize.

Here is all you need to learn **jsPDF**: [jsPDF - HTML5 PDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf)

**EDIT:**

It's important to know that to put images in the pdf you need to use them in base64. There is an example on the site and it's really simple.

You can use [this site](https://www.base64-image.de/) to convert your images to base64.